# Interrupt Handler with click event

Tags: android, android-handler

Consider following code :

```
 ImageView v = (ImageView)findByViewId(R.id.picture);
 // do something with v
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startGame();
        }
    }, 1500);
```

After 1.5 seconds the `method` `startGame()` is executed.
If the user wants to skip this waiting time, he should be able to click on an image to call `startGame()` immediately without calling `startGame()` after 1.5seconds again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop your handler you need to use the following method.

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Referring to : [RemoveCallBacksAndMessages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29)

Hope it helps.